# Setting hint text in a text field in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield, hint

Can some one suggest the best way for setting hint text(not default text) for a text field  in Ruby on Rails. Currently I am using this:

```
<%= text_field_with_auto_complete
  "customer", 
  :contact_person, { 
    :value => 'last, first',
    :style => 'color:#aaa;width:11em;', 
    :onfocus => "if(this.getValue()=='last, first'){this.clear();this.style.color = '#000';}",
    :onblur => "if(this.getValue()==''){this.setValue('last, first');this.style.color = #aaa';}" 
  } %>
```

The text field is attached to a model and in turn to a value in a database. Also, the same html that is used in index.html is also used in edit.html and hence when I try to edit the field, the default value shows up instead of the value from the database. What is the correct way to do this?

Note: I am not trying to set a default value but just a hint to what needs to be entered in the text box.

Thanks,

Raja Ram

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using the HTML 5 `placeholder` attribute, and then using a jQuery plugin to make it work on older browsers (like [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder), but there [are many others on Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+placeholder)).

You can [see this technique used in production here](http://www.dinevore.com/signup).

Comment: +1 for HTML5 :) actually most of plugins work through placeholder attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try this jquery plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hint

or choose here:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/hint

For prototype

http://davidchambersdesign.com/autopopulating-input-fields-with-prototype/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there something similar to this in the Prototype library?? I am currently using Prototype library.