# How to add hint text to a text field (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My ERB code is:

```
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Phone Number (Optional)" %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :phonenumber %>
    </div>
```

How can I leave text in the field which is deleted when the user clicks on the field? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting hint text in a text field in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071978/setting-hint-text-in-a-text-field-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `placeholder: "text"` option to `text_field`.